# How to count number of users selected in text box facebook API send method

Tags: php, facebook

I want to count the number of users to whom I have send the message.
Below are the code working fine but I am not able to the number of user.

```
<script>
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
     FB.init({appId: '123456789', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

     FB.ui({
         method: 'send',
         name: 'chandigarh',
         link: 'http://test.in',

         },  requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(response)
{
    if(response) {
        alert(response.length);
    }
}
</script>

<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> Facebook Invite Friends</a>
```

Comment: That is not possible, the Send dialog does not give any response data. What for would you need this information anyway? In case you are thinking about “rewarding” users in any way for sending out invitations using this method, please be aware that you are not allowed to do that. Go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) before implementing anything like that.

Comment: I was just testing this. method: apprequests is giving me the count in array so I was just trying if we can count with send method too Thanks for your reply